# MongoDB returning two array while using alias

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am a json in mongodb. The structure is below --

```
{
    id: "1",
    name: "sample",
    user: [
      {
        data_alias: "ex",
        value: "efg"
      }
    ]
}
```

Now I want the the data_alias to be data after mongodb returns the result.

When I am using below query --

```
db.coll.find(
    {"id":"1"}, 
    {"data": "$user.data_alias","_id": 0,"value":1}
)
```

Now it is retuning data like --

```
{
    "user": [
        {
            "value": "efg",
        },
    ],
    "data": [
        "ex"
    ]
}
```

But I want the returning value should be like --

```
{
    "data": "ex",
    "name": "sample"
}
```

Also I have tried with aggregate function

```
db.colls.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "id": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "data": "$user.data_alias"
    }
  }
]);
```

Both the queries returning same result.

Comment: Have you tried with `"$user.0.data_alias"`?

Comment: @Héctor now it's returning only one array . "user" : [ { "value" : "efg", }, ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `$unwind` the `user` array and `$project` to your expected output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: "sample"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$user"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      "name": 1,
      "data": "$user.data_alias"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sDxmuWeRqGB) for your reference.

Comment: Is it possible if my document is not an array rather than object like  {
    id: "1",
    name: "sample",
    user: [
      {
        data_alias: "ex",
        value: "efg"
      }
    ]
  }

Comment: not sure If I am understanding correctly.. but it seems that the document structure is the same as the original one so I do not quite understand the difference

Comment: For example --  https://mongoplayground.net/p/J8TIoL-YCe6

Comment: If you are fairly familiar with traditional relational databases, you can think `collections` in MongoDB as `tables` in RDBMS and `documents` in MongoDB as `rows` in RDBMS. Your array of documents actually is a collection of documents, which can be mapped to a table of rows. Your query, as a set-based operation, will produce the same result format for every row/document. So actually you are working on an array of 1 element(which is your example document), instead of working on a single document.

Comment: Sorry my question was wrong . Actually instead of fetching only first element, I need to find a match and return all the element. For example I need to find out the data where name=sample . and return all user array . It is simple but the problem arises when I am using Alisas to remove the underscore. Hope I am clear now.

Comment: You are looking for something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sDxmuWeRqGB)?

Comment: Thanks again ray . Yes that's exactly what I was looking for. If possible I would give you another upvote.

Comment: @Soham I have updated both the question and the answer to reflect your intention

Comment: Thanks again and apologies for the confusion.